# Checking if certain phrases are on a website with python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I've written a function that is ment to check if a phrase is in a certain website, however, it is always telling me that it isn't in the website even when it is. I'm relativly new to webscraping so any help would be appreciated.

```
def check_availability(url,phrase):
    global log
    try:
        # page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')

        if phrase in soup.text:
            return False
        return True
    except:
        log += "Error parsing website "
```

this always returned true for some reason please help.

Comment: Ignore the commented-out bit.

Comment: can you show us the example of your use case and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified function:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def url_contains(url, phrase):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
    return phrase in soup.get_text()
```

Example:

```py
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss'

>>> url_contains(url, 'Princeps mathematicorum')
True

>>> url_contains(url, 'foo bar')
False
```

Slightly optimized:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=4)
def get_soup(url):
    return BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

def url_contains(url, phrase):
    return phrase in get_soup(url).get_text()
```

This caches the `soup` obtained from a url, so you can repeatedly query many phrases for a given url. For the above: the first query takes ~1/3s; subsequent queries against that URL take ~4ms.